# Want to print a n*n matrix in zigzag pattern

Tags: java

This is my code:

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println("Enter the value of N: ");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n1 = sc.nextInt();
        int max = 0, min = 0;
        if(n1<=50){ 
            for(int i=1;i<=n1;i++){
                for(int j=1;j<=n1;j++){
                    max = n1*i;
                    min = (max-n1)+1;
                    if(i%2!=0){ 
                        while(max<=min){
                            System.out.print(max);
                            max--;
                        }
                    }
                    if(i%2==0){ 
                        while(min<=min){
                            System.out.print(min);
                            min++;
                        }
                    }   
                }
                System.out.println("");
            }   
        }
        else
            System.out.print("Invalid Value of n1");
    }
}
```

the problem is to print a zigzag matrix like 
if we enter n=4 then the output should be like:

```
4 3 2 1 
5 6 7 8
12 11 10 9
13 14 15 16
```

and if we enter 3 it should come like

```
3 2 1
4 5 6
9 8 7
```

now in the above code its going to a infinite loop

Answer (score 2):

Considering it is most likely some kind of a homework, I won't hand you a solution as it takes away the learning process. Instead, I'll just give you some hints.

- You need 2 nested `for` loops, the outer one for rows and the inner one for columns.
- Find out what the max and min numbers in a given row are. They are connected to the row number.
- If the row number is odd, start with the max number and go down. If it is odd, start from the min number and go up.